# SIGABRT in simple message box Qt program

Tags: qt

Got an error running the following problem:

```
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QApplication>
int main() {
    QApplication app();
    QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::Critical,
                       QObject::tr("text1"),
                       QObject::tr("text2"),
                       QMessageBox::Ok);
    msgBox.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

[image]

The program breaks at `QMessageBox msgBox(...);`

The call stack is:

[image]

EDIT: Even after i have added `QApplication` instance in XTerm window named `qtcreator_process_stub` i see the following:

> QWidget: Must construct QApplication before a QWidget

Comment: Create a QApplication instance first.

Comment: @Evgeny Added this line `QApplication app();` No difference.

Comment: What's the call stack at the point where the SIGABRT is generated?

Comment: Can you move back up the call stack from the crash point and print the message parameter that's being passed to `QMessageLogger::fatal`?  As far as I can see there are only two ways this can happen from within `QWidgetPrivate::QWidgetPrivate` -- 1) lack of an app instance (which you've fixed) and 2) a version incompatibility in the libraries.

Comment: @G.M.: Another possibility might be the absence of `app.exec()`. The main event loop of `QApplication` must be in execution.

Comment: @Azeem `QMessageBox` has its own blocking [`exec`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#exec) method.

Comment: @G.M.: Yup. Thanks! Just tested it without the main event loop `exec` and it worked. I assumed that it needed the main event loop `exec` as in the case of `QTimer` but it doesn't.

Comment: That's the "most vexing parse" - you didn't create a `QApplication`; you just declared a function returning a `QApplication`!

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks, it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
QApplication app();
```

doesn't create a `QApplication` object - it actually declares a function taking no arguments and returning a `QApplication`!  This is sometimes known as the "[most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)".

To actually construct the application object, you need to provide the program's arguments:

```
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

The full program is then

```
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::Critical,
                       QObject::tr("text1"),
                       QObject::tr("text2"),
                       QMessageBox::Ok);
    msgBox.exec();
    return 0;
}
```